# Angular ngZorro: [(ngModel)] does not pre set <select> tag value

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, ng-zorro-antd

I'm currently working on a front end solution that is built with Angular 6 and the framework Ng-Zorro 7.5

I have some list of reasons that I succesfully display as the code below, where reasonList is a array of the type `Reason`

```
export class Reason{
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

**Reasons.component.html**

```
 <div nz-col nzSpan="11">
  <nz-form-item>
    <nz-form-label [nzSm]="10" [nzXs]="24">
      Reason
    </nz-form-label>
    <nz-form-control [nzSm]="14" [nzXs]="24">
      <nz-select formControlName="reasonSelectControl" 
      (ngModelChange)="getSelectedReason($event)" nzPlaceHolder="select from list" [(ngModel)]="selectedReason">
        <nz-option *ngFor="let reason of reasonList" nzLabel="{{reason.name}}" nzValue="{{reason.id}}">
        </nz-option>
      </nz-select>
    </nz-form-control>
  </nz-form-item>
</div>
```

I can display the whole list of **reasonList**, select a value and get the id, so far so good.
Now, when I want to the option to be pre-set on my **Reasons.component.ts** with a value dynamically generated on my OnInit I can't display the value, it keep showing a blank space as follow:

[image]

I tried with every possible value for my **selectedReason**: a string with the Id of a Reason, a number with Id of a Reason, the whole complex object and the do a `selectedReason.id` in my reasons.component.html, but nothing works. Can you guys pleas help me?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ng-zorro. Does it work when you use Angular without ng-zorro, i.e. <select> instead of <nz-select> etc. ?

Comment: why would you put formControlName with [(ngModel)] on same input? you should choose one (reactive forms or plain), also please do not use nzLabel="{{someVariable}}" instead use [nzLabel]="reason.name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a  `form = new FormGroup( ... )` that contains your `reasonSelectControl` you can use this on `OnInit`

```
this.form.get('reasonSelectControl').setValue(this.reasonList[0].name);
```

I usually use the first element in the array.